# How to create an instance of class and implement it in a subclass?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, instance

How would I create an instance of a class to use as an attribute in another class? I believe this is what I need to do:

```
ClassA a1 = new ClassA(); // ClassA is the super class
```

This is where I get stuck, if my above code is even correct. How do I actually use this in a subclass of ClassA, say ClassB? So if ClassA has 'name' and 'age' and ClassB has 'tenant' what do I need to do in order to give tenant a name and age?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: You've gotten four answers and have not up-voted or accepted any -- why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ClassB extends ClassA` then `ClassB` will inherit all of the properties of `ClassA`. Here is a quick example:

```
public class ClassA {

     private String name;
     private int age;

     public ClassA(String name, int age)
          this.name = name;
          this.age = age;
     }

     public String getName() {
          return name;
     }

     public int ageGetAge() {
          return age;
     }
}

public class ClassB extends ClassA {

     private String tenant;

     public ClassB(String name, int age, String tenant) {
          super(name, age);
          this.tenant = tenant;
     }

     public String getTenant() {
          return tenant;
     }
}
```

For these classes, if you create a `ClassB` object in some part of your program you will be able to call the methods `getName()` and `getAge()` because `ClassB extends ClassA`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     ClassB object = new ClassB("me", 0, "you");
     System.out.println(object.getName());
     System.out.println(object.getAge() + "");
     System.out.println(object.getTenant());
}
```

This bit of code would output the following:

```
me
0
you
```

There are slightly different ways of going about this depending on whether various variables are `protected`, `private`, or `public`. I would recommend reading more about visibility and such.

Best of luck with your endevours.

Comment: That's straightfoward, but what if my main is separate from ClassA and ClassB? So I need to  feed ClassB the instance values from ClassA along with its own.

Comment: Do you mean turn a ClassA object into a ClassB object? The above code will work if the main method is in a separate class from ClassA & ClassB

Comment: Thank you, I think I have it!

Answer (score 0):

If Class B extends Class A, then you can automatically access the name and age elements of Class B as long as they are not private when declared in Class A

You can just do `classBInstance.name = "bob";`

Answer (score 0):

well Class B inherits from Class A. so in your constructor for Class B you have call the constructor of the super class using Super() then when you want to uuse attributes from the super class in the sub class you would just use super, so super.getAttribute() for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use the idea of classes and subclasses, and the use of protected fields:

```
public class ClassA {

    protected String name;
    protected int age;

    public ClassA(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    private String tenant;


    public ClassB(String name, int age, String tenant) {
        super(name, age);
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB b = new ClassB("Carol", 23, "some tenant");
        String tenant = b.tenant;
        int age = b.age;
        String name = b.name;

    }
}
```